# Prepare unique values for utf_unicode_ci in php

Tags: php, character-encoding, collation, unique-constraint

I need to read values from an ISO-8859-1 encoded file in PHP and use PDO to write them to a database table that's encoded `utf8_unicode_ci` and has a unique index. Sometimes the data is missing special chars which leads to duplicate key errors. Example: the data contains "Entrainement" and "Entraînement". Is there a PHP string function I can use to avoid this?

Preferably a conversion function so I don't have to iterate over the whole array to check if a value was already inserted.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$values = array("Entraînement", "Entrainement");
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;charset=utf8", "user", "pw");
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'UTF-8'");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(myvalue) VALUES(?)");
$already_inserted = array();
foreach($values as $v) {
    $v = $v_inserted = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', $v);
    // Do magic string conversion here
    // $v_inserted = collation_convert($v_inserted)
    if(isset($already_inserted[$v_inserted])) {
        continue;
    }
    if($stmt->execute(array($v))) {
        $already_inserted[$v_inserted] = true;
    }
```

}

This example should only insert "Entraînement" and skip over "Entrainement".

In the original program I'm using Doctrine ORM instead of PDO so I can' do much in SQL. Also, I have special chars in the whole Latin1 range - French, German, Spanish, etc.

I can't change the DB field definition to `utf8_bin`because it's part of an ecommerce package - all sorts of things might break.

Comment: How exactly are you reading the values, can you show the code you are using to write the data into the table?

Answer (score 1):

Well you should definitely convert the values to UTF-8 and use UTF-8 connection encoding. Otherwise your application cannot take advantage of the UTF-8 at all because your application will only be able to send and receive characters that ISO-8859-1 contains. This is very, very little amount compared to Unicode ☹.

---

That is unrelated to your issue*, in the `unicode_ci` collation, `î` is considered same as `i`.
If you need to consider them as different characters use some other collation:

```
SELECT 'î' = 'i' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
//1

SELECT 'î' = 'i' COLLATE 'utf8_bin'
//0
```

There is no German** collation so I guess `utf8_bin` is what you want here.

---

*There is only an issue when the declared connection encoding does not match the encoding of the physical bytes you send over. I.E. If you send ISO-8859-1 bytes with UTF-8 connection encoding, you will get crap if not an error. And vice versa.

**I looked that up from your profile, if you in fact need some other language there might be a collation for that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I see that I might have defined my problem too sloppy. I have expanded my question - now you can see that I can' do much on the DB side and need a PHP function that does the same collated string comparison/conversion that MySQL does.

Comment: @chiborg you cannot insert into the table unless you remove the unique constraint or change the collation. I recommend changing the collation of the column. Or do you mean consider them the same in php already? In that case you can use `intl::Collator::compare` http://www.php.net/manual/en/collator.compare.php

Comment: @chiborg Still not really sure what you are trying to do but can't you just use `INSERT IGNORE INTO..` that way you don't need to check in PHP whether something is inserted. It will just silently fail.